# ExtJS Combobox Error: Cannot read property 'store' of undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, filtering, store

I have a Tab panel with few tabs. One of them contains grid and the grid contains 3 itmes: 
1 item with editor type "textfield", and 2 items with editor of type "combobox".

**The problem:** I want to filter the combobox store based on the previous combobox. But for some reason it works only the first time. After that the store returns undefined.

Here is my code:

```
items:[{
    xtype: 'grid',
    id:'schema',
    border: false,      
    data:[],
    columns:
    [{
        text     : 'Size',
        dataIndex: 'size',
        id: "SizeDropdown",
        width    : 200,
        sortable : true,
        editor   : {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            id:'SelectSize',
            editable:true,

            valueField: 'typeValue',
            displayField: 'typeValue',
            mode:'local',
            lastQuery: '',
            listeners:{
            },
            store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
                fields: ['size', 'typeValue'],
                data: [
                        ['char', '12'],
                        ['char', '30'],
                        ['char', '31'],
                        ['int', '250'],
                        ['int', '500'],
                        ['int', '1000'],
                    ]
            }),
            allowBlank: false,
            validator: function(input){                                 
                return true;
            }
        }   
    }],
    listeners: {
        beforeitemclick: function (eventThis,  record,  rowIndex, e) {

            var SizeStore = Ext.getCmp('SizeDropdown').editor.store

            SizeStore.clearFilter();
            SizeStore.filter('size', record.data.type);
        }
    }
```

***'record.data.type'*** returns '**char**' or '**int**', depending on the previous combobox and the filtering works okay. But only the first time. After that it breaks here:

```
var SizeStore = Ext.getCmp('SizeDropdown').editor.store
```

And returns:

```
Cannot read property 'store' of undefined
```

I'm using ExtJs "4.0.7"

Comment: You could move the store outside of your class. Define it normally. I don't think it's good idea to have store defined inside the editor. Also would you be able to re-create your problem at fiddle.sencha.com with that help would be much easier.

Comment: @pagep thanks, I declared the store outside the class and it worked. :) Write it as an answer if you want and i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring the store outside the Tab class did the job.

Here is what I did:

```
        var sizeDropdownStore = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
            fields: ['size', 'typeValue'],
            data: [
                    ['char', '12'],
                    ['char', '30'],
                    ['char', '31'],
                    ['int', '250'],
                    ['int', '500'],
                    ['int', '1000'],
            ]
        });


        ...{
            xtype: 'combobox',
            id:'SelectSize',
            editable:true,
            valueField: 'typeValue',
            displayField: 'typeValue',
            mode:'local',
            listeners:{
            },
            store: sizeDropdownStore,
            allowBlank: false
        }...
```